# Why is the contour integral in upper plane different from the lower plane in this case?

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

Why is the contour integral in upper plane different from the lower plane in this case?

$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\mathrm{d}k\frac{1}{(k+a)(k-a)(p-k-b)(p-k+b)}$

where Im[a] and Im[b] are negative and p is real. Besides, Re[a] and Re[b], and p are positive.

The the poles in complex plane are shown below: 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n3ZGc.png)

$\frac{1}{2a[(p-a)^2-b^2]},\frac{1}{2b[(p-b)^2-a^2]},-\frac{1}{2a[(p+a)^2-b^2]},-\frac{1}{2a[(p+b)^2-a^2]}$

I get these residues by just putting $a$ into the other three denominators $(k+a)$, $(p-k-b)$, $(p-k+b)$. and I also use the same procedure to the other three poles $p+b, -a, p-b$ (since each pole is a simple pole). I think the summation of these four poles should give zero. What's the problem?

Comment: What are the residues that you obtain. The sum of the residues has to be zero in this case. Otherwise, you have a mistake in the calculation.

Comment: Oh, I see the residues. I believe the second and fourth residue should be minus from what you write.

Comment: I get one of the residue $Res_{k=p+b}=\frac{1}{(p+b+a)(p+b-a)(-2b)}$ by put p+b into k+a, k-a, p-k-b

Comment: We can also get the other answers by the same procedure.

Comment: @JamesLiu That is not how you compute a residue. In order for this heuristic to work, you need to change the initial expression it so all signs of $k$ are positive. (i.e. have the last two factors in the denominator be $(k-(p-b))(k-(p+b)),$ otherwise you will be off by a minus sign for two of them.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen Thanks for your answer, but I still get the similar answer: $\frac{1}{2a[(p-a)^2-b^2]},\frac{-1}{2b[(p-b)^2-a^2]},\frac{-1}{2a[(p+a)^2-b^2]},\frac{1}{2a[(p+b)^2-a^2]}$
The problem is that $p+a$ and $p+b$ appear in the denominator

Comment: Oh, I've found that their summation would give zero, i.e. that's the correct answer. Thanks everyone a lot. Though it's not a good question, I still appreciate that you guys are willing to spare your time to answer me.